# Prime ideals in the ring of $p$-integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1 \neq 0$ and suppose $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $R \backslash \{\, 0 \,\}$
containing no zero divisors. We have the relation $\sim$ defined on $R\times S$ via
$$(a, b) \sim (c, d)\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad ad = bc.$$

If we define the $p$-integers as $R_S$ for $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $S = R \backslash p\mathbb{Z}$, I want to verify that there are two prime ideals of the $p$-integers, one corresponding to the zero ideal and one corresponding to the prime $p$. I have been given the hint that it may help to regard $R_S \subset \mathbb{Q}$ via
$$R_S=\{\, \tfrac ab:a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, p \nmid b \,\}.$$

I am not sure where to start, can anyone give any guidance? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The construction of $R_S$ from $R$ is known as the *localisation* of $R$ at $S$, and is also denoted $S^{-1}R$.

A basic fact on localisations, which is worth proving yourself, is that there is a canonical morphism
$$R\ \longrightarrow\ S^{-1}R,$$
and that it induces a *bijection* between the prime ideals of $S^{-1}R$ and the prime ideals of $R$ that do not intersect $S$. This bijection then immediately shows you what the ideals corresponding to the zero ideal and the ideal $p\Bbb{Z}$ are.

Comment: No , Zp is not same as the localization of Z at (p)